# How to specify ul type/class in different nested layers in CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

When writing html/doxygen, ul, li are frequently used. For a nested list. I want to the first layer to be "disc", the second layer to be "square", and the thrid layer to be "dash".

```
<ul>
    <li> ...
    <ul type=square>
         <li> ...
         <ul class="dash">
              <li> ...
              <li> ...
         </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Is there way to avoid typing things like *type=square* or *class="dash"*. Once I write a nested ul list, it can be default be set to different type and class depending on what the nested layer it is located?

Anyway to do it in CSS?

Comment: You cannot set a class in CSS. Classes are set in the markup language (HTML or XML).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS in this manner:

```
ul {
  list-style: disc
}

ul ul {
  list-style: circle;
}

ul ul ul {
  list-style: square;
}
```

**Demo:**http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1736/

Comment: Works perfectly to select different styles. But I don't want to use "circle", but want to use a predefined ul class "dash", anyway to select it?

Comment: add ul.dash wherever you want it to use

Comment: Tring to set the 3rd level as
ul ul ul.dash {
}
do not work. I have to redefine the class using "ul ul ul > li:before". But anyway, your answer has resolved my problem perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`square` is a valid `list-type`, below is an example. You can use `:before` pseudo selector to achieve dash.

```css
 ul[type=square] {
      list-style: square;
    }

  ul.dash {
      list-style: none;
    }
 ul.dash >li:before  {
      content:"-";
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -14px
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li> ...
    <ul type=square>
         <li> ...
         <ul class="dash">
              <li> ...
              <li> ...
         </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know how to define the "dash" class. I just want to know how to automatically invoke it in certain level of a nested ul, without specifying class="dash"